# C0222 error when opening project (then goes away)

Tags: codesys, iec61131-3

I have many methods the return value of which is a REFERENCE TO in my libraries. When I open the library, I see a C0222 error in the message window for each of these. If I compile the library, the message goes away. The code compiles and works under both CODESYS and TwinCAT.

Is this just a CODESYS glitch, or is there a reason for that message?

Comment: Does rebuilding the project make them go away? If the answer is yes, then most likely the project gets loaded first when opening the project, before loading the library.

Comment: The error is when I open the library, in the library's instance of CODESYS, there is no project involved.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this happens.
Make a PRG or FB with a method that returns a reference to something, the precompiler throws this error:
`C0222: Outputs can't be of type REFERENCE TO`
However the code compiles fine, and there are no messages in the normal 'Build' section.

(I think that's why the message 'disappears' in your case. The Messages box switches from Precompile to Build when you compile the library.)

I'd suggest listening to the precompiler and avoid returning a reference.

For example:

```
METHOD Method1 : REFERENCE TO INT
VAR_INST
    i : INT;
END_VAR

Method1 REF= i;
```

Call like this:

```
result : REFERENCE TO INT;
result REF= Method1();
```

This code works fine. When you change result you actually change the i variable inside the method. This feels very hacky!

And when you change i from a VAR_INST to a VAR, the code compiles ok, but the reference now points to invalid memory because i goes out of scope when you leave the method.

Edit:

You can use a pragma to disable the error message. Add the following line in every method where you return a reference:

```
{warning disable C0222} // Disables Precompiler error C0222: Outputs can't be of type REFERENCE TO
METHOD Method2 : REFERENCE TO BOOL
VAR_INPUT
END_VAR
```

Comment: I am not sure I am following you. You suggest I refrain from returning a reference (why?), but your suggested solution returns a reference, no? I can say that, for sure, using a VAR_INST to instantiate the referenced function block is not a solution for me, and I am not even sure I have a problem to start with. Please note that my existing methods do not return references to variables that go out of scope. The references are (permanently) valid, and the code runs without issues. That being said, you answer does give me an idea...

Comment: One more thing... You are right that the error appears in the "Precompiler" view, I did not even know this was a thing and found out, thanks. That being said, once the code has compiled, the errors no longer show if I go back to "Precompiler".

Comment: I tested having a VAR_INST declared as a "REFERENCE TO", itself assigned from inside the method to an instance located outside the method before doing a REF= to the return value (in case that would have gotten rid of the precompiler error, the source of the REF= assignment being within the scope of the method), but unsurprisingly it did not. It really is the method declaration that causes the issue, not the code of the method.

Comment: I don't understand why returning REFERENCE would be a problem. I'm using it a lot without any issues, for method chaining etc. Only reason I can think is somebody returns a reference to temporary local method variable...

Comment: @Quirzo, I feel the same, yet I wanted to see if anyone has an explanation for that error message. It is also not great having a bunch of errors shown every time you open a library.  I also notice every time I edit code, the errors come back, but I notice them less because after compiling once the "precompiler" view is no longer active, but the methods have the red underline in the project tree, also not great.

Comment: I updated the answer with a way to disable the error message.